# Clustering Data Using Gower and Kmeans

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, gower-similarity

I am trying to do clustering on my data which consists of both categorical and continuous variables. I have some questions which I would like to ask:

1. I am going to use the Gower Distance measure to find the similarties/dissimilarties between data points is that ok?
2. Can I use K-Means clustering for mixed variables to perform clustering? If not I will use Two-Step Clustering but can Two-Step Clustering be performed in R? Also, if so which Hierarchical Algorithm will I have to use?

Thanks

Comment: Please search "K-means Gower" on the site. The question was asked several times already

Comment: @ttnphns - I have researched even before questioning here but there is not like a definite answer to my question as some of the answers are saying you can use K-Means some not and I don't know what I should actually do

Comment: Please see my latest addition to here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15313/3277

Comment: Two-step clustering (found in SPSS) acceps interval or nominal variables, but not ordinal or binary. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/116859/3277. For nominal ones, it uses log-likelihood distance.

Comment: @ttnphns - I know about the Two Step Clustering but I am using R and it seems that  there is no package that can be applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K-means can only be used in data sets where you can compute the arithmetic *mean*.

Use hierarchical clustering instead. It can use distance matrixes, including Gower distances.

Answer (score 0):

No, k-means can only work for numeric data. If you have mixed-type data, then you can try k-prototypes, which integrates k-means for numeric data and k-modes for categorical data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).